# Use two different paddings for two different browsers

Tags: css, web, stylesheet, padding

I want to add two different padding for Chrome and Firefox, and want to use it in same style sheets. (cant use separate sheets) These are the two styles I want.

for Firefox

```
padding: 0 0 0 14px !important;
```

for Chrome

```
padding: 0 0 0 0px !important;
```

My knowledge in style sheets is minimum, don't even know this is possible or not. Any sort of help is welcome, Thanks.

#### Update

code for my button is

```
<button class="buttonClass" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" onclick="buttonToggle(this);" id="butid">
                            <input type="image" class="ns" onclick="buttonToggle(this);" value="" />
```

Comment: This isn't possible withoug User agent sniffing which isn't recommended, can i ask why you need to do this?

Comment: well, I have button which is pre-done by dojo. I want to set a image to that button. when I set padding according to Chrome it is not visible in Firefox. and when I use padding for Firefox it shows extra space in chrome.

Comment: Not a good idea to try setting different CSS for different browsers. You'll end up with things looking different when you test in IE, Chrome, Safari and Firefox, not to mention older versions of IE.

Comment: I just want change this one line according to browser :(

Comment: Can you update your post with the html and css assigend to the button, these quirks usually mean there is another issue going on

Comment: Fix the root of the problem, don't bandaid over it with browser specific fixes.

Comment: I added the code as an update.

Comment: Without the CSS there is not a lot i can figure out, it could be an issue with the box sizing, try adding this to you css file and tell me if it helps

`button{    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;

}`

Comment: Sure, I'll have a look and let you know, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved It by adding this to deal with Firefox.

```
    @-moz-document url-prefix(){
            #butFullScreen .ns, #butFullScreen .fs {
                padding: 0 0 0 14px;
                height:0px;
                width:0px;
}
```

while using this to other browsers

```
width:14px;
height:14px;
color: transparent;
```

Thanks a lot for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

i haven't tried it. But it should work like this.

here's the link to browser detection via jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

```
$(function() {
  if ($.browser.mozilla) {
    $('body').addClass("firefox");
  } else if ($.browser.chrome) {
    $('body').addClass("chrome");
  }
});
```

Comment: This has been dropped as of jQuery 1.9 please don't use this